# @Before AbstractTestNGCucumberTests should be executed per scenario java

Tags: testng, cucumber-jvm

I am using Cucumber with Test Ng to do integration test with Behavior Driven Development. I've below behavior runners

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "json:test-output/cucumber-
                           report/report1.json", "html:test-
                           output/cucumber-report/report1.html" }, 
                glue = "com.package.behavior", 
                features = "src/test/resources/behavior/feature1/")
public class BehaviorRunner1 extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @Before
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        log.error("Executing scenario "+scenario.getName());
    }
}
```

**AND**

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "json:test-output/cucumber-
                             report/report2.json", "html:test-
                             output/cucumber-report/report2.html" }, 
                 glue = "com.package.behavior", 
                 features = "src/test/resources/behavior/feature2/")
public class BehaviorRunner2 extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @Before
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        log.error("Executing scenario "+scenario.getName());
    }
}
```

The folder structure is :-

```
src
 |
 |-test
    |
    |-resources
        |
        |-behavior
            |
            |-feature1
            |    |
            |    |-feature-file1.feature
            |-feature2
            |    |
            |    |-feature-file2.feature

feature-file1.feature
------------------------------------
Scenario : Test Scenario1

feature-file2.feature
------------------------------------
Scenario : Test Scenario2
```

When I execute the scenario I see below printed twice.

    Executing Scenario Test Scenario1
    Executing Scenario Test Scenario1
    Executing Scenario Test Scenario2
    Executing Scenario Test Scenario2

I would like to see below output

    Executing Scenario Test Scenario1
    Executing Scenario Test Scenario2

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I just want the Behavior runner 1 execute the scenarios from the folder feature1, Behavior runner 2 execute the scenarios from the folder feature2.

Comment: Can you show us how does your `.feature` files look like ? Do they have the same names for scenarios in them ?

Comment: No the scenario names are different. I've listed the sample contents of the feature files above.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add this information about the feature files ? Also please mention the version of cucumber-jvm that you are using along with TestNG version as well.

Comment: I've updated the all the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two log entries because there are two `@Before` hooks. Hooks are global in nature, ie all hooks found in the glue option package structure, and will be executed twice in this case for each scenario. Keep only one before hook. Or if you want more than one hook use the order value of the annotation to create a chain. Also you can use tags in before annotation to filter which before hook to run.

You might want to look at moving the hooks to a separate class inside the glue option package. Easier to find out the hooks. Also using the current setup you have to include the test runner classes inside the glue option, thus giving them two responsibilities.

Comment: _italics_ Also you can use tags in before annotation to filter which before hook to run. _italics_ <br/> I can't use tags because I have about 70 feature files and about 3000+ scenarios. I tried to do this <br/> You might want to look at moving the hooks to a separate class inside the glue option package. Easier to find out the hooks. Also using the current setup you have to include the test runner classes inside the glue option, thus giving them two responsibilities. <br/> but then my code is not reusable.

Comment: If u include multiple before hooks within the glue package value and without any kind of tag filtering u will have the current issue. What are u trying to reuse as the code sample does not shed light on that aspect?

Comment: I was able to resolve by adding at the top of each feature file @OrderSubmit and then override the method `@Before("@OrderSubmit")
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {        ` in `public class OrderSubmitBehaviorRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {`